# Creating Function to Count Values Based on Datetime

Tags: python, function, datetime, count

I have data that look like this:

| activity_date | company_name | new_company_status | calling | visit | quotation | po |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/10/2022 | ABC | Yes | Yes | No | No | No |
| 04/10/2022 | ABC | No | No | No | Yes | Yes |
| 05/10/2022 | DEF | No | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| 06/10/2022 | XYZ | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No |
| 07/10/2022 | DEF | No | No | No | Yes | Yes |
| 08/10/2022 | XYZ | No | Yes | No | No | Yes |

1. I want to create a function that will check every same `company_name` that has at least one `new_company_status` as a 'Yes' that turn into a 'Yes' `calling` and count the sum of it even in the different date.
2. I want to create a function that will check every same `company_name` that has `calling` as a 'Yes' that also has `po` as a Yes even in the different date.

This is the **pseudocode** that I created:

1.

```
for every same company name:
    if 'new_company_status' = 'Yes':
        check 'activity_date'        # for new company status if it is a Yes
    if 'calling' = 'Yes':
        check 'activity_date'        # for calling if it is a Yes
    if calling_date >= new_company_date:
        new_company to call =+ 1
```

2. 

```
for every same company name:
    if 'calling' = 'Yes':
        check 'activity_date'        # for calling if it is a Yes
    if 'visit' = 'No':
        if 'quotation' = 'No':
            if 'po' = 'Yes':
                check 'activity_date'   # for po if it is a Yes
    if po_date >= calling_date:
        call to po += 1
```

**Expected output**:

1. 1
2. 3

How to code the pseudocode into Python? Can anyone help me? Thank u in advance.

Comment: You haven't provided the expected output

Comment: Your pseudocode makes no sense to me.  What do `check 'activity_date' ` and `new_company to call =+ 1` mean?

Comment: @CryptoFool hi, so I want to check the date of the `new_company_status` since for every same company name there can be a 'Yes' and a 'No' on a different date.  If it at least has one 'Yes' for the `new_company_status`, next it will check the `calling`, if it has a 'Yes' even on a different date, it will count as 1. I'm so sorry if my pseudocode is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe, you can use boolean operations and [`groupby.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

#### question 1

```
# define boolean masks
m1 = df['new_company_status'].eq('Yes')
m2 = df['calling'].eq('Yes')

# count the number of companies
# with at least one occurrence of m1 and m2
(m1&m2).groupby(df['company_name']).any().sum()
```

Output: `1`

#### question 2

```
# counting the companies with at least one calling AND one po as Yes
df[['calling', 'po']].eq('Yes').groupby(df['company_name']).any().all(axis=1).sum()
```

Output: `3`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, the code for the 1st question works just fine, but when I tried the question 2 code into larger data, the output gives me the number of all the company names on the data even if there are only 7 data of po, but when I tried applying the 1st question code into the 2nd question, it returns 0

Comment: I think it's missing the `.eq('Yes')`, see edit (untested)